# Understanding expl3's \exp_args:NV

Tags: expl3, expansion

In the example below, I would have expected `\exp_args:NV` (1.) and `\exp_args:Nv` (3.) to work as `\exp_last_unbraced:No`+braces around the variable (2.).  Instead they absorb stuff past the variable.
What could I be missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\l__erw_foo_tl{{x}{y}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item %\exp_args:NV\use_i:nn\l__erw_foo_tl
\item \exp_last_unbraced:No\use_i:nn{\l__erw_foo_tl}
\item %\exp_args:Nv\use_i:nn{l__erw_foo_tl}
\end{enumerate}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\exp_args:NV` takes a variable and expands to the content *as an `n` type argument*, so with

```latex
\exp_args:NV \use_i:nn \l__erw_foo_tl
```

the expansion is

```latex
\use_i:nn { <content of \l__erw_foo_tl> }
```

Similarly for `\exp_args:Nv`

```latex
\exp_args:Nv \use_i:nn { l__erw_foo_tl }
```

results in exactly the same

```latex
\use_i:nn { <content of \l__erw_foo_tl> }
```

In both cases, `\use_i:nn` requires *two* arguments, and here we've only supplied one, so it absorbs whatever follows.

In contrast, `\exp_last_unbraced:No` (or `\exp_last_unbraced:NV` or ....) explicitly do not brace the last argument. This is a relativity rare requirement, and is intended as a slightly higher-level expansion than `\exp_after:wN` but not as common/convenient as the `\exp_args:N...` family. The `o`-type argument takes one token, which by convention should not be in braces but will work with them - you are I think confusing with

```
\item \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn \exp_after:wN  { \l__erw_foo_tl }
```

which is explicitly `w` in nature of the first argument (token).